# How to Optimize CPU Usage in Live View Application when introducing Scrolling Animationi In Elixir Phoenix Framework LiveView

Tags: javascript, css, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a live view application that displays exchange rates data. Within the application, there is a box called "announcement" which shows scheduled or adhoc messages. Sometimes the message consists of around 3 lines, but occasionally it can be longer. However, the message box can only display up to 3 lines. So, when the message exceeds 3 lines, I decided to implement a scrolling animation behavior.

Here's how I implemented it:

First, I added a Phoenix Hook to listen for when the message box is loaded. If the message box is loaded, I assume that there is a message to display.

```
Hooks.MessageBox = {
  mounted() {
    updateAnimationForMessage("message", this);
  },
  updated() {
    updateAnimationForMessage("message", this);
  },
};
```

Then, I added a JavaScript function to check the number of lines in the current message.

```
  const messageList = document.querySelector("#message-list");
  const content = messageList.querySelector("li:first-child");
  const cssCompute = window.getComputedStyle(content);
  context.pushEvent(event, {
    number_of_lines: Math.floor(
      parseInt(cssCompute.height) / parseInt(cssCompute.lineHeight)
    ),
  });
}
```

In the LiveView, I created a list with 10 rows of `<li>Message here</li>` elements using a for loop. These messages are scrolled up using CSS animation set to run infinitely. I push the number of lines count to the LiveView. The LiveView receives the number of lines and adds the CSS animation with inline styling.

```
["animation: message-slideup #{calculate_message_animation_time(number_of_lines) * 10}s linear infinite"]
```

I expected this code to work without any unexpected behavior or increased CPU usage. However, when I deployed it to production, I noticed that the CPU usage doubled with 200 clients accessing the application. Therefore, I am seeking help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Why wouldn't you expect an increase in CPU usage?  Even running things in separate threads the CPU has to handle each thread?  I'd say that your expectation of no increase in CPU usage may be a bad assumption to start with.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci Yeh slight increase about 3%,4%,5% percent I can accept. But this situation CPU is double. usually CPU is 20% this time after the deployment CPU is 50%. That's why I am concern about that.

Comment: Well I'd say your best course of action would be to try to isolate where the CPU usage is coming from.  Maybe start with a profiler. Or try to build something somewhat parallel but simpler and then add back pieces until you see where the CPU spike happens.  As it stands there's no quick or simple answer that anyone can give you--too many potential reasons for the CPU spike.